# std vector of Eigen matrices results in run time crash on some Windows machines

Tags: c++, eigen

I have the following declaration for a vector of Eigen matrix. Thanks to Louen for helping me with this declaration. However during runtime the program crashes at this declaration. This doesn't happen on all machines. Just one I have come across. It may be because I am missing the Eigen::aligned_allocator as part of the declaration. However I am not able to figure out how to include it in the declaration. This is a vector of Eigen matrix initialized to zero. Any help is much appreciated.

```
std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> inv_K_mat2(42, Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(4, 5));
```

Comment: What does your debugger say about it?

Comment: _"the program crashes at this declaration"_ — How do you know? BTW, aligned allocator is needed only for fixed-size matrices according to [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html). It explicitly says that: _"For other Eigen types, such as `Vector3f` or **`MatrixXd`**, no special care is needed when using STL containers."_.

Comment: Without a [mre] this would just be guesswork -- it is not unlikely that the actual issue is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I have run it in the debugger and stepped through the lines. It is at this declaration the crash happens and I get the typical "Windows is looking for a solution message". After posting the message I found out that the machine I was running is W7 OS and so far I have used only W10. It is highly likely the problem may be related to the OS

Answer (score 0):

The Win32 header files are different between different releases of Windows.  If you build with the Win 10 headers, then it's likely that the resulting code is incompatible with something in Win 7.
What compiler are you using?  In Viz Studio there are [macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=msvc-160) available that let you specify the version of the headers to include.

Comment: I am using VS 2017. Will look into the macros. This was a test I ran on a remote machine without realizing it is W7. There isn't many users on W7 anymore